Swagger Springfox not working API documentation
I cannot access the /v3/api-docs endpoint or any other swagger endpoints. I get an 403 forbidden error in postman and an error in the IDE console saying:

"No endpoint GET /v3/api-docs "

Here is the Security config class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtFilter jwtFilter) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf ->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth
                        .requestMatchers("/init",
                                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                "/swagger-resources/**",
                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                "/webjars/**",
                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                "/swagger-ui/index.html")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).sessionManagement(session->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }


}

The swagger configuration class -
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}

And dependencies in the pom.xml file
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

I tried annotations @EnableSwagger2 and others such as @EnableSwagger2WebMvc etc. it didn't work. I allowed all the endpoints like this in requestMachers("/**").permitAll() I got a 404 not found error this time.

i suggest you drop springfox as it is not maintained, and instead move over to springdoc-openapi instead

Did you read https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

@Toerktumlare Yes I just found out. i added springdoc-openapi instead and had to reconfigure the swagger config file. now it works fine. Thanks!
